# Add new data in to jsonb column

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have `jsonb` column with next data:

```
{
    'key1': 'data1'
}
```

with some object:

```
const myObj = {
   'key2': 'data2'
}
```

I need write SQL query to add `myObj` in to `jsonb` column, with result like:

```
{
    'key1': 'data1',
    'key2': 'data2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `||` operator, i.e.

```
update <tablename> 
  set jsonb_column = jsonb_column || '{"key2":"data2"}'::jsonb 
  where ...
```

Here is the [`documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

Comment: then use this: coalesce(jsonb_column, '{}'::jsonb) || '{"key2":"data2"}'::jsonb or put a default '{}'::jsonb to jsonb_column